# Are the extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$ normal over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

are the extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$ normal over $\mathbb{Q}$

I am not really sure how to start. 
I tried to construct a counterexample for the first extension. The second seems to be true.
But I did not succeed.

Any hints?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A compositum of normal extensions will be normal.

Comment: Don't forget that $5$ has three cube roots.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Obviously $X^3-5$ is a counterexample for the 2nd case.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: So when I can show, that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}))$ are normal, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is normal? Or when I can show, that one extension is not normal, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ can not be normal?

Comment: Hint for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$: suppose $L$ is an extension of it and $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(L)$.  Then the restriction of $\sigma$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ is uniquely determined by the images of $\sqrt{2}$ and of $\sqrt{3}$.  What can you say about those images?  Are those images in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$ is not normal over $\mathbb{Q}$:

The polynomial $X^3-5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. (Eisenstein criterion with $p=5$) And $X=\sqrt[3]{5}$ is a root.
But $X^3-5=(X-\sqrt[3]{5})(X-(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{5})(X+\sqrt[3]{-5})$.
Hence it can not be factored into linear factors over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$.

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is normal, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ are field extensions of degree 2 and therefore normal.
So the composition $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is normal.